# Change the pitch of the sound but not changing its playback speed unity3d

Tags: android, ios, audio, unity-game-engine

I am just developing a sample app in unity (as a beginner) so i am stuck at a point, i need to change the sound which is recorded (like in Talking Tom app).

i am done with recording the audio but when i increase the pitch of the sound the speed of the playback is also changed. i need the playback speed is normal only pitch must be changed.

so can anyone help me on this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not much of an answer but, you can't.

Comment: is there any way i could control the playback speed..

Comment: Ehm.... that is done by changing the pitch.

Comment: let me elaborate i want the sound playback speed is normal change the sound(make sound like a baby).

Comment: That is not something Unity can natively do. Your best bet is to process the audio in external software. Or perhaps there is a library available. But to waste resources on it to do so in real-time seems a bit pointless.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of researching, I found that what you're trying to do is called "pitch shifting". It involves a lot of math and mucking about with sound packets apparently because changing the pitch of a sound, automatically changes it's playback speed. Getting it back to the speed you want while still keeping the audio at something considered "normal" is no walk in the park.

In any case, since Unity3D uses C#, you might (and I stress the word **might**) be able to use [this open source library](http://skypefx.codeplex.com/) to get the sound effect you need. It's based on [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) (also open source, and C#) so you should theoretically be able to use it, or parts of it in your project.